# How to write a query that looks for null in any field?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to write a query in Oracle that will return the count of any row in the table with a null in any of the fields where they meet another parameter. Right now, I'm just using

```
select count(*) from my_table where trunc(sent)>(to_date('01-APR-01', 'DD-Mon-YY')) and
field_1=null
or field_2=null
or field_3=null
etc.
```

Is there a better way to do this? And will combining "and" with "or" the way I have work the way I want it to at all?

Comment: Why is the `TRUNC()` function needed around the `sent` column? If `TRUNC(sent)>TRUNC(dt)`, then we know that `sent>=TRUNC(dt+1)`. I think there's a much clearer way to express the idea that `sent` is on or after midnight of April 2nd, and a way which won't disable Oracle from making effective use of an index with a leading column of `sent`.

Comment: Create an `UDF`, and query `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` and let Oracle do rest of the stuff for you. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

No. There may be a different way to phrase it (using `COALESCE` instead of `OR` for example), but you will have to explicitly enumerate all the columns no matter what you do, so it does not really make a difference.

More importantly, though, `x = null` does not work at all.

You need to use `x IS NULL`.

> will combining "and" with "or" the way I have work the way I want it

When in doubt, use parentheses:

```
WHERE a AND (b OR c OR d)
```

Comment: Excellent. Also, I just realized my original question was incomplete. You answered half of it though! I'll go back and edit it to make it complete if that's ok with you.